# Reused code-chunks in Rmarkdown not working with magrittr pipe

Tags: r, knitr

The following is based on content within [The R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/reuse-chunks.html) which suggests that named code chunks can be re-used.

The following minimal (albeit contrived) example works as expected:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library (magrittr)
```

```{r filterCyl, include=FALSE, eval=FALSE}
dplyr::filter(cyl == 6L)
```

```{r filterGear, include=FALSE, eval=FALSE}
dplyr::filter(gear == 4L)
```

```{r, eval=FALSE}
mtcars %>%
  <<filterCyl>>
```
````

However, replacing the lower-most block with:

````
```{r, eval=FALSE}
mtcars %>%
  <<filterCyl>> %>%
  <<filterGear>>
```
````

...results in the following being shown in the resulting HTML:

```
mtcars %>%  
  <<filterCyl>> %>%  
  dplyr::filter(gear == 4L)
```

The `<<filterCyl>>` block is not being substituted in as I'd expect.

If I remove the `%>%` operators from that final block, it *does* get subsituted in; however, the resulting R code isn't valid.

**Does this appear to be a bug?** **Is there some workaround that could be used here?**

Comment: Is there a reason for this method instead of using a function? e.g., `filterCyl <- function(x) {x %>% dplyr::filter(gear == 4L)}`?

Comment: This does seem to be inconsistent with the statement "the marker <<label>> does not have to be on a separate line. It can be embedded anywhere in a code chunk." . I'm not sure if the cookbook is wrong or if this is a bug. You might first try to file an [issue with the cookbook](https://github.com/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/issues) or maybe a [knitr issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/). This seems like a very good reproducible example in either case. I'm not sure this is pipe specific; seems to not work if you use `+` or anything else either.

Comment: @Matt - The reason I laid it out in that way is I'm putting together some training material, by showing each step in a pipeline of transformations. Being able to combine them as I've tried to do would (in theory!) be an elegant solution.

Comment: @MrFlick - Agreed... You've confirmed my suspicions on this. I don't believe anything I've tried to do goes against what the cookbook suggests is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the confusion---the cookbook was wrong. Currently `<<>>` only works on a separate line. This restriction doesn't seem to be necessary. I tend to change it. Please feel free to file an issue to the knitr repo. Thanks!

Comment: @YihuiXie - Not at all. I've been using knitr a lot recently and this is the first time I've come up against something like this without an obvious work-around.

Thanks for confirming... Just in the process of doing that right now.

I also tried having a look through the knitr source code to see where this subsitution takes place without any luck.

Comment: The substitution takes place here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/55a2df9353af1157b3954a968cfef5c1e30dd64c/R/parser.R#L384-L399 The regular expression `ref.chunk` comes from https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/55a2df9353af1157b3954a968cfef5c1e30dd64c/R/pattern.R#L34 If you want to provide a patch (Github pull request), I'll definitely appreciate it! I'm not sure how hard it will be, though.

Comment: Pending a long-term fix... I have created a script that takes the `Rmd` as input, expands all of the `<<...>>` references and then passes this revised file to `rmarkdown::render()`. The interested reader can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/Rich-F-G-Mills/6b5a1f4a0ccbbcdc4ea324b6f497065e). It is far from robust but works in this particular case.